# How to correctly setup a C language project in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, iar, multi-project

I'm an experienced Java developer, and I'm very familiar with Eclipse. Lately I've been trying to migrate a [**Texas Instrumental**(BLE)](http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/538/t/123464.aspx), **IAR** *C language* project, into Eclipse, without using IAR official Eclipse plugin, I just want to use Eclipse as my code browsing IDE, while I learn how things works, and follow up the tutorial, and in the future use Eclipse to develop.

I've been trying for a day now, to migrate the project, but there is something I'm missing something regarding Eclipse *C language* support.

There are some types defined in an **.h** file, in project "**A**", which is referenced in an other **.c** file in project "**B**", and Eclipse although it can "*go to declaration*", it shows a compilation error in project "**B**".

I've noticed in other cases of the same scenario, that I don't need to point to any of the folders as source folder, as long as the folders are under the project root directory, they are added to the build path of that specific project, and also imported into a project "**B**" with only referencing the "**A**" project in the project properties, is this correct?

Also, I've noticed that in the *C language* both projects could reference each other, without Eclipse troubling me so I assume this is legit, therefore I assume there should be a *C language* multi-project structural pattern I should follow, where can I find such detailed specification?

Thanks,

Adam Zehavi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally understood that this cannot be done... alas I've worked hard to been able to edit my code in Eclipse while running, debugging, and deploying the program to the Microprocessor via IAR IDE.

Comment: It would be nice if you documented HOW you did that here.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_c_c++_guide/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/eclipse_c_c++_guide_cdt_u_dbg_src.htm) (Common Source Lookup Path preference)

Edit: in my Eclipse CDT Helios, I do like this:

Right click on project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths And Symbols.

then choose my language (GNU C) and add the folders with the header files that I want to include.

That operation could be done automatically in one step for every configurations (Run/Debug) or just for the active configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols Then click Export Settings... to save the include paths and/or symbol definitions to a file. In your other project, you can then use Import Settings...